# Getting the value inside a random key in PostgreSQL JSONB?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

is there a way to extract the value from a jsonb if your key is "random"?
Example:

```
{"6": {"id": "6", "name": "book-name", "genre": "history", "book_id": "3"}}
```

The key here is "6" which in my case is a pseudo-random number. It's always different for every row, so in a way inaccessible by simply pointing towards it. (jsonb->'key')
I've tried almost everything I could find and still have no solution to this.
Is there a way to get to the value in this case?
The PG version is 9.6.
Thanks :)

Comment: Please show what you tried. Please add more sample data and expected output. Please explain more detailed what your use case looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear to me what you want as the output, but maybe you are looking for this:

```
with sample_data (js) as (
  values ('{"6": {"id": "6", "name": "book-name", "genre": "history", "book_id": "3"}}'::jsonb)
)
select x.v
from sample_data sd
  cross join lateral jsonb_each(sd.js) as x(k,v)
```

The above will return:

```
v                                                                   
--------------------------------------------------------------------
{"id": "6", "name": "book-name", "genre": "history", "book_id": "3"}
```

If you want the individual key/values then you can use

```
with sample_data (js) as (
  values ('{"6": {"id": "6", "name": "book-name", "genre": "history", "book_id": "3"}}'::jsonb)
)
select d.*
from sample_data sd
  cross join lateral jsonb_each(sd.js) as x(k,v)
  cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(x.v) as d(k,v);
```

The above will return:

```
k       | v        
--------+----------
id      | 6        
name    | book-name
genre   | history  
book_id | 3
```